# How to show error when I put wrong value in string to array android

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps

I write a code for showing map marker in maps activity. When I want to search some array value in `EditText` and I input wrong value I want to show error message here is my `btncari.onClickListener`

```
btncari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
if (editcari.getText().toString().isEmpty() || editcari.getText().toString().equals(null)
                        ) {
                    Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "Masukkan Nama Wisata", duration).show();
                } else {
                    for(int i=0; i < nama.length; i++) {
                        if (nama[i].toLowerCase().contains(editcari.getText().toString())){
                            marker.remove();
                            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i])).title(nama[i]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_wisata)));
                            CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]))
                                    .zoom(18)
                                    .build();
                            CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos);
                            myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            }
        });
```

i have try to handle some error like `if (editcari.getText().toString().contains("array value"))` but it doesn't work. also i've tried with `Arrays` like this

```
if (Arrays.asList(nama).contains(editcari.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "welcome", duration).show();
            }
            else
        {
            Toast.makeText(FragmentPeta.this, "Error", duration).show();
        }
```

the difference is when I use `Arrays` it will always show `"Error"`eventhough I input the right value from array. So when I put right value on editsearch it will zoom to marker that I typed. the problem is the `"error message"` is still keep showing.

I put  `if Arrays.asList` above the `if (editcari.getText())`

Answer (score 0):

When using arrays yourlooking at a specific index of the array, not the entire array. Using a List on the other hand youcan call `list.contains(value)' to parse through the entire list to verfiy if the value is within the contents of such list.

```
if(!list.contains(value){
//show error related msg to user
}
```

Comment: i dont understand your statement. Where do you declare your Array/List, its all case-sensitive.

Comment: i declare Array in Fragmentpeta, i want to show an error message when i input value that doesn't exist in my array `nama`.  it's like `if (Arrays.asList(nama).contains("//randomvalue") { //show error message}`

Comment: Look at my revised answer

Comment: `value` is array value right? but i want to check from edittext. it's like `if i put random value on edittext it will show error`